# How to stop appending to a list and start another list when doing iteration using for function?

Tags: pandas, csv, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to add more users that will answer some questions. But the new file to save their answers, shows answers in one row. So, the users and their answers do not match their respective headers. In this case, I entered 3 users and the answered 3 questions; and received these error message when creating a table using Pandas.

pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 5, saw 9

I tried using tuples and nothing works. Thanks.

```
def example():
"""Get answers from the new users and save them in file answers.csv"""
#`Open file named filename_answers in append mode a+
   filename_answers = answers.csv
   fanswers_new_users = open(filename_answers, "a+")
   writer_answers_new = csv.writer(fanswers_new_users)
   questions_add_user = str(input("Do you wish to add another user?Enter Yes/No to continue"))
   q_ = questions_add_user.title()
   print("These are new user answers:\n")
   while q_ == "Yes":
    #headers_questions_enumerate is a list holding all enumerated questions
      for preguntas in headers_questions_enumerate[:]:
         print(preguntas)
         preguntar_1 = str(input("Please, Answer the question:\n"))
         preguntar_ = preguntar_1.title()
         respuestas_new_user.append(preguntar_)
      questions_add_user = str(input("Do you wish to add user?Enter Yes/No to continue \n"))      
      q_ = questions_add_user.title()   
      if q_! = "Yes":
      for rep in respuestas_new_user:
         respuestas_new_user_save.append(rep)
      values_dictionary.append(respuestas_new_user_save)
      for separados in values_dictionary:
         pegar_defintivo.append(separados)
      writer_answers_new.writerows(pegar_defintivo)
      fanswers_new_users.close()
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reset your `respuestas_new_user_save` list for each user.

```
import csv

def example():
    """Get answers from the new users and save them in the file answers.csv"""
    filename_answers = 'answers.csv'  # Make sure to enclose the filename in quotes
    fanswers_new_users = open(filename_answers, "a+")
    writer_answers_new = csv.writer(fanswers_new_users)
    questions_add_user = str(input("Do you wish to add another user? Enter Yes/No to continue"))
    q_ = questions_add_user.title()
    print("These are new user answers:\n")
    
    while q_ == "Yes":
        respuestas_new_user_save = []  # Reset the list for each user
        for preguntas in headers_questions_enumerate[:]:
            print(preguntas)
            preguntar_1 = str(input("Please, Answer the question:\n"))
            preguntar_ = preguntar_1.title()
            respuestas_new_user_save.append(preguntar_)
        
        questions_add_user = str(input("Do you wish to add user? Enter Yes/No to continue\n"))
        q_ = questions_add_user.title()
        
        if q_ != "Yes":
            writer_answers_new.writerow(respuestas_new_user_save)  # Write the user's answers to a new row
            fanswers_new_users.close()
            break

example()
```

Comment: Thanks. How I reset?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to reset using seek(0) and always get the same result. I have checked the pointer position in the While and For sections and remain the same. So, the seek(0) does not work in this case. Thanks for your time answering my question.